# Rails devise LDAP user groups by memberuid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I don't understand how this gem `devise_ldap_authenticatable` works with groups. Does it rely on the memberOf objectAttribute of users ? Well I don't have this overlay. I only have posixGroups with memberuid attributes. I had thought this was enough for the gem to work, but the `Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_groups('username")` method keeps returing empty arrays.

(The authentication itself works well, but I can't retrieve user groups)

My config :

```
development:
  host: ldap.myorg.com
  group_base: "ou=Group,dc=myorg,dc=com"
  port: 636
  attribute: uid
  base: "ou=People,dc=myorg,dc=com"
  admin_user: "cn=intranet,dc=myorg,dc=com"
  admin_password: "somepw"
  ssl: simple_tls 
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

I DO specify a `group_base: "ou=Group,dc=myorg,dc=com"` So it shouldn't have any problem finding the groups like `"cn=Some Group,ou=Group,dc=myorg,dc=com"` for a user `"uid=username,ou=Group,dc=myorg,dc=com"` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*cough* At the time of writing, the gem has a hardcoded value that only allow for `uniqueMember` attributes. See this [link](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/issues/185). However it should be possible to match for another attribute changing only a string in one of the gem source files.